# execution default of spring-boot-maven-plugin repackage failed

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I've got a simple [project](https://github.com/lapots/hero-journey) that is doing nothing for now and which is just a simple `Spring Boot 2` application which supposed to use `java 9`.

When I run `mvnw clean package` over `hero-journey` folder I get this error

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.M5:repackage (default) on project hero-journey-web: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.M5:repackage failed.: RuntimeException ->
 [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.M5:repackage (default) on project hero-journey-web: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin
:2.0.0.M5:repackage failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.0.M5:repackage failed.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor.visitModule(ClassVisitor.java:148)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:762)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:663)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:527)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.createClassDescriptor(MainClassFinder.java:267)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.doWithMainClasses(MainClassFinder.java:223)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.findSingleMainClass(MainClassFinder.java:203)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.findMainMethod(Repackager.java:365)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.findMainMethodWithTimeoutWarning(Repackager.java:354)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.buildManifest(Repackager.java:325)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:255)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:248)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:193)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.repackage(RepackageMojo.java:221)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.execute(RepackageMojo.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 28 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hero-journey-web
```

It does not provide any particular information about the cause except `RuntimeException` and that something happen (it seems) on class parsing.

`mvn -version` looks like this

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0
Maven home: L:\installed\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 9, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
```

What is the problem?

My main `pom.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.lapots.breed.hero.journey</groupId>
    <artifactId>hero-journey</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>hero-journey</name>
    <description>Start the journey towards the greatest powers</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>hero-journey-web</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>9</java.version>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>google-drive-repository</id>
            <url>file://L:/google-drive/m2-artifactory/mvn-releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>google-drive-snapshot</id>
            <url>file://L:/google-drive/m2-artifactory/mvn-snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>google-drive-releases</id>
            <url>file://L:/google-drive/m2-artifactory/mvn-releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>google-drive-snapshots</id>
            <url>file://L:/google-drive/m2-artifactory/mvn-snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

My subproject `pom.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.lapots.breed.hero.journey</groupId>
        <artifactId>hero-journey</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>hero-journey-web</artifactId>
    <description>Hero Journey - web application</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you provide your pom settings? (especially for the repackage configuration)

Comment: @LHCHIN done. But I you also could access throught the link to github I provided

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems I ran into existing [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10647)
So I used the solution provided by [@wilkinsona](https://github.com/wilkinsona) to resolve it. I added `configuration` with `mainClass` and project was successfully built.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.lapots.breed.hero.journey.web.HeroJourneyWebApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for springboot-kafka 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] springboot-kafka ................................... SUCCESS [  1.016 s]
[INFO] springboot-kafka.model ............................. FAILURE [  1.862 s]
[INFO] springboot-kafka.producer .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] springboot-kafka.consumer .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.252 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-07T20:58:34+03:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project springboot-kafka.model: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project springboot-kafka.model: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find main class
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.addMainAndStartAttributes(Packager.java:249)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.buildManifest(Packager.java:231)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.write(Packager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.repackage(RepackageMojo.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.execute(RepackageMojo.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :springboot-kafka.model
```

My main pom.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-kafka</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <modules>
        <module>springboot-kafka.producer</module>
        <module>springboot-kafka.consumer</module>
        <module>springboot-kafka.model</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

I put `<plugins>` tag in `<pluginManagement>` tage according to the following code, and my problme solved.

```
 <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

I put a configuration (tag) to pom.xml with Reference to main class. That solves the problem.

```html
<build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.example.springbootdocker.SpringBootDockerApplication</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
 </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way . You add  a configuration to pom but this way only works in the compiler. It doesnt work real world. If you want to  use .jar or .war . It will not work. 
**You must add com.lapots.breed.hero.journey file under java file.** Then It always works

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we had micro-services (Spring boot App) and common codes were split into libraries. The libraries also were built as a Spring boot App and later we removed the resources and test folders. But since we didn't want the main App.java, we removed that too. That's when we were not able to build the application, but we already had `spring-boot-maven-plugin` under `<pluginManagement>` but were still not able to do the `clean install` in STS `4.15.3.RELEASE`. So we added an extra configuration inside the same `plugin`.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

This worked fine